# 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit, modernizr

Does anyone know what this error means? This message started to appear in the Chrome console this week and is throwing an error in jquery `modernizr`. Doesn't seem to be much helpful info out on the web either.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a result of a [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) test. It is checking to see if indexedDB exists by attempting to access all known browser versions (`mozIndexedDB`, `webkitIndexedDB`, `indexedDB`, etc).

You can safely ignore it, it is just saying that if you are using `webkitIndexedDB` for actual code (ie storing data in it), that you should be using indexedDB instead.

If you are not using indexedDB at all, you should create a new custom [build of modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download) that has **only** the detects that you actually need. More than likely this is a version with *everything* in it, which drags down the performance of the entire site.

Also, if  you are using Modernizr 1.7 - thats *super* now. I would really recommend updating!

Answer (score 0):

Also, for anyone not using Modernizer, `es6-shim` has a similar test.

Answer (score 0):

Double Check that all functions exist if you are using a view (Especially if you moved stuff around).

For some strange reason one of my views in a .Net MVC application was not displaying. That error was popping up.

I moved a function somewhere else in the code and it could not find that function anymore which may be one of the reasona why that error popped up. The error went away after I pointed it to its new location.

```
@functions{
    function do(){
        @* ///Do something. *@
        <C#function>
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just started getting this in Chrome from running hasOwnProperty on a loop of the 'window' property list.  Fortunately it's only debug code but annoying nonetheless!

> (index):118 window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
>   (index):118 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.

```
function listObject( _type )
{
    for ( var f in this )
    {
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty( f ) )
        {
            if ( this[ f ] && this[ f ].prototype instanceof _type )
            {
                console.log( f );
            }
        }
    }
}
```